# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, ros-hydro, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tried the [3D Visualisation tutorial for the turtlebot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/hydro/3D_Visualisation). I'm having a hard time launching the kinect on my turtlebot laptop. Below are the terminal logs. (note that user@eko-gateway is my turtlebot laptop)

```
user@eko-gateway:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch 
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/8a2a9104-1c4a-11e4-9db6-48d2241d08a9/roslaunch-eko-gateway-9515.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://10.42.0.1:34058/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads
 * /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/min_range
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/min_range
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id
 * /camera/driver/depth_registration
 * /camera/driver/device_id
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_hw (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_sw (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_hw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.1:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [9533]
[ INFO] [1407210380.835627720]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [9555]
process[camera/debayer-3]: started with pid [9576]
process[camera/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [9591]
[ INFO] [1407210384.245259146]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1407210384.247759899]: 1. device on bus 001:77 is a SensorV2 (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id 'A00364A15558132A'
[ INFO] [1407210384.256431370]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1407210384.380931401]: Opened 'SensorV2' on bus 1:77 with serial number 'A00364A15558132A'
process[camera/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [9633]
process[camera/rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [9672]
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [9695]
[ INFO] [1407210387.201221214]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1407210387.201518310]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1407210387.253713214]: Camera calibration file /home/user/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00364A15558132A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1407210387.255078906]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1407210387.256739764]: Camera calibration file /home/user/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00364A15558132A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1407210387.259620976]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [9767]
process[camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [9862]
process[camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [9950]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [10021]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [10090]
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-13]: started with pid [10174]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14]: started with pid [10249]
process[camera/disparity_depth-15]: started with pid [10310]
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-16]: started with pid [10358]
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-17]: started with pid [10391]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-18]: started with pid [10438]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  virtual void openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startImageStream() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-openni-camera-1.9.2-0precise-20140720-0559/src/openni_device.cpp @ 224 : starting image stream failed. Reason: Failed to send a USB control request!
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 9533, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/8a2a9104-1c4a-11e4-9db6-48d2241d08a9/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/8a2a9104-1c4a-11e4-9db6-48d2241d08a9/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1*.log
[depthimage_to_laserscan-18] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/8a2a9104-1c4a-11e4-9db6-48d2241d08a9/depthimage_to_laserscan-18*.log
```

The 3rd step which is the start rviz on my workstation computer(running ROS indigo) also came out nothing after ticking Laserscan and DepthCloud. All I had was the default image of the turtlebot and grids.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188899/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-%27openni_wrapper::openniexception%27/) by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It says at the top that you launched this from user@eko-gateway. However,

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch
```

must be run on the Turtlebot. I know that the turtlebots by default have username "turtlebot", so I'm just curious if this was ran on the turtlebot or your workstation?

---

Originally posted by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) with karma: 301 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-08-05**:
Ahh I'm sorry, I've edited my post to mention that the user@eko-gateway is my turtlebot laptop.
Anyways, I've just updated my depthimage_to_laserscan package. I'll post my progress after I try running this tutorial again later.

Thank you for your input btw!

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-08-06**:
yes after updating the package, the process no longer being terminated after process[depthimage_to_laserscan-18].

I believe, this is now solved.

**Comment by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) on 2014-08-06**:
Sounds great. Let me know if this gives you any issues with depth registration; my depth_registered stream is all 0's at the moment.

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-08-07**:
How do you check that?

**Comment by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) on 2014-08-07**:
turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch seems to run depth_registration by default. Running rostopic echo camera/depth_registered/image_raw should show you the values of the depth_registered image, and whether or not it works.

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-08-13**:
sorry for the late reply, indeed my rostopic echo camera/depth_registered/image_raw also came out as nothing.